# Uncertainity calculation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements, error-analysis

> The length ($l$) and width ($w$) of a rectangle is ($15.6\pm 0.1$) cm and ($10.80\pm 0.01$) cm respectively. Calculate the area and uncertainity.

Solving:

$$\text{Area}=15.6\times 10.80$$
$$\text{Area}=168.48cm^2$$
$$\text{Uncertainity}=(0.1\times 2)\pm (0.01\times 2)$$
$$\text{Uncertainity}=0.22cm^2$$

But the result I should be getting is $\text{Area}=168cm^2$ and $\text{Uncertainity}=1cm^2$ ?

Comment: by inspection, you can ignore the uncertainty in $w$ (it's a 100 microns) and use $\delta A \approx w\delta l = (10.8cm)(0.1cm)=1\, cm^2$. BTW: what makes you think you just add twice the uncertainties?.

Comment: @jeb:  surely "inspection" is never going to reveal the intended purpose of this calculation, and so can never reveal whether 100 microns is or is not significant for that purpose.

Comment: @WillO I always act as if the intended purpose is to get the right answer. Drove my teachers nuts.

Comment: How do you come to this formula for uncertainty? The general formula can be found for instance on Wikipedia, [in fact your problem is an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Example).
But @JEB is right since the relative magnitude of $\delta w$ is lower by two, you can in principle ignore it...

Comment: @failtrolol It's lower by a factor 10, and for a nearly square rectangle, that means it is 100 times less important than the other uncertainty.

Comment: @JEB it is true that I've phrased it in an inaccurate manner. I meant to say, "with the correct error propagation formula, the magnitude of $\delta w^2$ is lower by two, therefore it can, in principle, be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do these problems in general. You have a physical quantity that is a function of several (let's say 2) variables:

$$ A = f(x, y) $$

So how does an uncertainty in some value of $x$, say $x_0\pm\delta x$,  affect $A$? That's basic calculus:

$$ \delta A_x = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_o, y)\delta x $$

Likewise for $y$:

$$ \delta A_y = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y_0)\delta y $$

Now how do you deal with multiple uncertainties in each variable?
Well, it depends. Are your measurements correlated? And if so, how much are the correlated?

If they are not correlated, and we're going with that, then you add them in quadrature:

$$ \delta A^2 = \delta A_x^2 + \delta A_y^2 $$

That independent variables with uncorrelated uncertainties add in quadrature is extremely fundamental, and you should really try to understand it. It appears in many places, in many ways.

Back to your problem:

$$ f(x, y) = xy $$

so that
$$ \delta A_x  = y(\delta x)$$

$$ \delta A_y  = x(\delta y)$$

Note the symmetry there in $x, y \rightarrow y, x$. This reflects the fact that the labeling of width versus length is arbitrary.

Moreover, if you don't have any intuition as to why that has to be the form: draw a few rectangles with variable widths and fixed length--what's the area of the part that doesn't overlap?